# Template Django include tags do not display

Tags: python, django, templates, openshift

I'm porting my project over to OpenShift. I'm having issues displaying the includes in my .html files and I cannot seem to figure out why - no error messages found with using `rhc tail app`. I've tried the usual things such as changing `include navigation.html` to `/static/navigation.html`

Here is the `dashboard.html` file:

```
<body class="en personalization results edit">
   <div class="masthead-wrapper container-fluid">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="masthead">

            {% include "navigation.html" %} 
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

and `navigation.html` is:

```
{% load base_extras %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/style/js.js"></script>

Stuff...
```

Also tried inspecting the object in chrome. I'm confused as to why I don't get an error on loading in the django framework. Because navigation is in the same directory as dashboard, I don't know why its not being pulled in.

Here is the `settings.py`

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '..', 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'), 
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

Comment: What is static files folder set to in `settings.py`?

Comment: Django discovers and uses templates in very specific ways:
Create a template folder in your root directory and place under it templates, app templates should have a parent folder with the name of the app.
static as you state above, has nothing to do with the STATIC assets, it should be pointing to a directory:
my_project_root/templates/static

Comment: @IanAuld STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '..', 'static') STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'), )

Comment: @petkostas I have put more info in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Navonod static files have nothing to do with templates, you are messing things up, static files are assets such as css,js templates should be located under PROJECT_DIR templates, if you are having problems loading static files (css, js) then you need to properly deploy your Django app:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

Comment: I have tried putting something in the STATICFILES_DIRS to make this work. However I do not understand why include navigation.html doesn't look in the templates folder - the same folder that contains dashboard.html

Comment: @petkostas Static files are file. I'm having trouble including within a template thats it. I cannot find in the documentation where the include goes to look for the included .html (I assumed it would be the same as the templates?)